# Как реализовать исправление раскладки в Elasticsearch?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Как реализовывается подобный функционал? В документации ничего нет, а в остальных источниках пишется, что раскладка заменяется до передачи запроса на поиск. Также видел, что предлагается реализация через `suggest`, но конкретных указаний нет.

Вопрос: как всё же это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
$rusLetters = ['й', 'ц'];
$engLetters = ['q', 'w'];
echo str_replace($engLetters, $rusLetters , 'qw');
```

Comment: я наделся что есть функционал у самого эластика. Нужно же понимать, с какого языка на какой переделывать, плюс учитывать что фраза может включать сразу 2 языка